# WebRDP not working properly over nginx reverse proxy configuration

Tags: http, nginx, https, rdp, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a FreeRDP client running in windows machine which is accessible over IP address and port number from external network(IP:PORTNUMBER). I have to proxy_pass my FreeRDP client through Nginx present on remote ubuntu machine so that HTTPS can be enabled on it. I have my own domain name with proper certificate enabled.

Example : FreeRDP URL - "http://15.206.114.133:8000/"

DomainURL : https://staging.gvbgeomatics.com/

Wanted FreeRDP to accessible on
https://staging.gvbgeomatics.com/machine/ --> http://15.206.114.133:8000/

Steps : 
1. On New Windows 10 Machine I have installed FreeRDP client and made it accessible over port 8000 and public Ip address over external network(12.12.12.12:8000).

2. I have a working website "https://staging.gvbgeomatics.com/" and I want my FreeRDP to redirect under my domain /machines

I have tried passing my FreeRDP Url under proxy pass.

```
location  /machine/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://15.206.114.133:8000/;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

It opens the front UI of freeRDP under

"https://staging.gvbgeomatics.com/machine/" but it does not allow me to login in into the machine.

https://pasteboard.co/IEvu5Pj.png "FirstRefrence"

But after login :

https://pasteboard.co/IEvv3Ts.png "SecondRefrence"

Error Message appearing

```
TypeError: this.sock is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I think FreeRDP uses 8000 for only UI which is HTTP traffic but RDP itself is not HTTP traffic and it seems to be on port 3389. You also should enable 3389 with nginx's TCP proxy.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/